# Vertical alignment (stretching height) for Adaptive Cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

According to these GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/484) and [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/1836) card elements should now have a `height` property with a "stretch" value, allowing for vertical alignment. I've tried this in Teams (Adaptive Card v1.0) and coudn't get it to work. The Schema Explorer makes no mention of height, although the `size` property was renamed into `width`.

Have I missed something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Adaptive cards for column size we need to define property as "width". here is the sample doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/card-schema#column)

Comment: Thanks @Arun-MSFT but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I had noticed "size" was renamed "width" as explained in GitHub issue #404:

_Because we are introducing a "height" property, it makes sense to also rename the "size" property of a Column to "width"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teams supports the schema here: http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json. Or more accurately, since the schema is an evolving document, this specific version https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/998628b3088ad23a0d8fe08934980ffb693c4123/schemas/adaptive-card.json.

That doesn't include the "height" property (indeed I don't think they've updated the schema yet?), so unfortunately, you can't use it for adaptive cards in Teams yet.